# How do I connect to iccube using Snowflake?

Tags: jdbc, iccube, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

after copying the latest version of the Snowflake driver in to the lib folder of iccube, starting the server and then performing the following:

1. Schema create - Wizard (Dimensions/Measures -> Table)
2. Relational Database
3. Connection details....

---

- Driver Type: JDBC
- Server Name:
  net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver
- DB Name:
  jdbc:snowflake://xxx-eu-west-1.snowflakecomputing.com
- User: dummy
- Password: xxx

I get the following error.

```
[     qtp525575644-48] [DEBUG] (13:21:33.986 UTC) [R] GWT 20 servlet-started
[     qtp525575644-48] [DEBUG] (13:21:34.031 UTC) [R] GWT 20 request-process-started [session:node0s0rjncom0tmx12mojb0y00nl60] OTHER (schema:none) GwtDiscoverTableNamesQuery cl_GWT_GwtDiscoverTableNamesQuery_1546953693969_1151490167
[     qtp525575644-48] [DEBUG] (13:21:34.031 UTC) [R] GWT 20 submit-tasks-started 1 q:0 t:0/8
[     qtp525575644-48] [DEBUG] (13:21:34.031 UTC) [R] GWT 20 submit-task-started GWT
[     qtp525575644-48] [DEBUG] (13:21:34.032 UTC) [R] GWT 20 execute-task-started GWT [LOCK:none]
[     qtp525575644-48] [DEBUG] (13:21:34.034 UTC) [JDBC] creating a new OLAP connection [780055920]
[     qtp525575644-48] [DEBUG] (13:21:34.065 UTC) [JDBC] opening a new DB connection [780055920]
[     qtp525575644-48] [DEBUG] (13:21:34.065 UTC) [JDBC] Postgres URL [-] [net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver] [null] [jdbc:snowflake://xxx.eu-west-1.snowflakecomputing.com]
[                  gc] [ WARN] (13:21:34.339 UTC) [GC] (PS Scavenge) : 14ms ( free:174MB / total:227MB / max:456MB )
[     qtp525575644-48] [DEBUG] (13:21:36.640 UTC) [JDBC] closing the DB connection [780055920]
[     qtp525575644-48] [ERROR] (13:21:37.119 UTC) [builder] validation error(s)
[BUILDER_JDBC_CONNECTION_CANNOT_BE_CREATED] JDBC connection for url 'jdbc:snowflake://xxx.eu-west-1.snowflakecomputing.com' and user 'pentaho_reporting' cannot be created due to error 'null'
    at crazydev.iccube.builder.datasource.jdbc.OlapBuilderJdbcConnection.onOpen(SourceFile:110)
    at crazydev.iccube.builder.datasource.OlapBuilderAbstractConnection.open(SourceFile:73)
    at crazydev.iccube.gwt.server.requesthandler.builder.handlers.datatable.GwtDiscoverTableNamesQueryHandler.doHandleImpl(SourceFile:65)
    at crazydev.iccube.gwt.server.requesthandler.builder.handlers.datatable.GwtDiscoverTableNamesQueryHandler.doHandleImpl(SourceFile:29)
    at crazydev.iccube.gwt.server.requesthandler.builder.handlers.common.GwtAbstractBuilderQueryHandler.unsafeHandleImpl(SourceFile:239)
    at crazydev.iccube.gwt.server.requesthandler.builder.handlers.common.GwtAbstractBuilderQueryHandler.safeHandleImpl(SourceFile:186)
    at crazydev.iccube.gwt.server.requesthandler.builder.handlers.common.GwtAbstractBuilderQueryHandler.handleImpl(SourceFile:178)
    at crazydev.iccube.gwt.server.requesthandler.builder.handlers.common.GwtAbstractBuilderQueryHandler.handleImpl(SourceFile:70)
    at crazydev.iccube.gwt.server.requesthandler.common.GwtAbstractQueryHandler.handle(SourceFile:75)
    at crazydev.iccube.gwt.server.requesthandler.common.GwtAbstractQueryHandler.handle(SourceFile:58)
    at crazydev.iccube.gwt.server.requesthandler.common.GwtQueryHandlerDispatcher.dispatchQuery(SourceFile:528)
    at crazydev.iccube.server.request.request.gwt.IcCubeGwtServerRequest$Task.unsafeExecute(SourceFile:629)
    at crazydev.iccube.server.request.task.IcCubeServerTask.execute(SourceFile:247)
    at crazydev.iccube.server.request.executor.IcCubeServerTaskRunnable.run(SourceFile:42)
```

Comment: Could you please paste the complete stacktrace? It seems the cause exception is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake jdbc driver throws a 'SQLFeatureNotSupportedException' with an empty message when calling setReadOnly to the connection.

We fixed this in our dev branch and will be available in the next release or as a pre-release.

PS: Discovering tables doesn't work very well, as a workaround you might add SQL queries as tables.